# Загрузка нескольких изображений в базу данных

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите пожалуйста скрипт рабочий, который будет загружать несколько большое количество изображений в базу данных и в каталог на сервере. Количество (3-20) не должно иметь значение, просто нужно чтобы они добавлялись каждая как новая запись.
Уже третий час сижу никак не могу сделать это.

Comment: Загрузите через готовый jquery, получаете от него массив имён и их через цикл в бд и на сервер.
http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.multiple.php Офф инфа PHP
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ готовый плагин

Comment: слишком много файлов для одной задачи, можете привести пример? Я был бы очень признателен Вам.

Comment: Закинул пример, для красоты можете такое реализовать уже через jQuery готовые плагины, там и JS придаст удобство

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот с загрузкой фото в upload

```
<?php
$dir = 'd:\uploads\\';//В linux в другую сторону слэши
$host = "host";
$username = "root";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "dbname";
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//Более корректный перебор по ключу и значению
foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$f) {
    if (!$_FILES['file']['error'][$k]) {
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k])) {//Проверка загрузки файла во временное хранилище
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $dir . $_FILES['file']['name'][$k])) {//Перемещение временного файла
                echo '<p>Файл: '.$_FILES['file']['name'][$k].' загружен.</p>';
            }
        }
    }
    $sql = "insert into file_multi values(NULL, \"{$_FILES['file']['name'][$k]}\")";
    $conn->query($sql);
}
echo "Успешно разружены все файлы";
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Это оно добавит в каталог сервера и в базу данных?

Answer (score 0):

Создание тестовой таблицы.

```
create table file_multi (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, filename varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

index.php
В этой файле выбираете файлы и передаёте форму на скрипт загрузки

```
<form action="file_upload.php" name="upload_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Файлы:<br />
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple />
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

file_upload.php
Получаете массив файлов и через цикл добавляете в БД

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "dbname";
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename) {
    $sql = "insert into file_multi values(NULL, \"{$filename}\")";
    $conn->query($sql);
}
$conn->close();
```

Также в файле можете посмотреть `var_dump($_FILES);` Увидите какие ещё и где поля передаются серверу.

Comment: Я конечно извиняюсь, но где путь к этому изображению, как его загрузить в каталог на сервере?

Comment: Скрипт рабочий без слов, добавляет в базу, но я буду очень благодарен если он еще и в каталог на сервере будет добавлять. Поставлю максимальную оценку за ответ ))

Comment: .___. толку от этих оценок =) Учитесь поиском пользоваться и фантазировать)

Comment: Искренне тебе благодарен, поставил + заслуженно. Все четко работает, большое спасибо!